# creacion de trigger SQL (productos, precio, stock)

Tags: mysql, mysqli, stored-procedure, trigger

Estoy en proceso de creación de un trigger que debe almacenar en una tabla **producto_entradas** que tiene la siguiente estructura

```
CREATE TABLE producto_entradas{ 
producto_entrada_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`rela_producto` INT,
`usuario`VARCHAR (50),
`cantidad_entrada_unidad` INT,
`fecha_entrada` DATETIME,
`precio_actual` DECIMAL(10,2)
}
```

en esta tabla se deberían guardar los datos correspondientes luego de la inserción de un producto nuevo. lo que me sucede es que yo tengo tablas diferentes para guardar los datos de cada producto. Por ejemplo tengo tabla productos, tabla producto_stock y la tabla producto_precio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como verán quiero guardar en la tabla producto_entradas datos de la 3 tablas anteriores y no tengo la menor idea de como hacerlo.
Lo que solicito es alguna ayuda, ejemplos o links a otras preguntas para poder crear un trigger que haga lo que quiero lograr.

Esto es lo que tengo hasta el momento pero no me cierra porque en teoría la variable stock y la variable precio no se insertan en la tabla productos sino en producto_stock y producto_precio

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
/*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' */
TRIGGER `trigger_insert_productos` AFTER INSERT ON `productos` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO producto_entradas
(`rela_producto`,`usuario`,`cantidad_entrada_unidad`,`fecha_entrada`,`precio_actual`)
   VALUES(NEW.producto_id,USER(),NEW.stock,SYSDATE(),NEW.precio);
  END;
 $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: *Como verán quiero guardar en la tabla producto_entradas datos de la 3 tablas anteriores y no tengo la menor idea de como hacerlo.* Para poder resolver esto  con un TRIGGER tendrías que tener a mano todos los datos necesarios para hacer la inserción en `producto_entradas` cuando el TRIGGER se dispare. ¿Es posible tener a mano en las inserciones de `productos` todos los datos necesarios para crear una nueva fila en `producto_entradas`? Si no es posible, significa que debes buscar otra solución, como definir reglas de integridad referencial o rediseñar las tablas.

Comment: @A.Cedano bien! tenia gran duda de si se podía hacer eso o no! Voy a seguir buscando formas de hacerlo que no sea así porque no logro tener todos los datos después de la inserción de productos :( de igual forma muchas gracias